# Does changing code of aspx in published website works?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a published website and I need to change only the ViewPage(.`aspx`) code that is giving me an error. If I change that viewpage will it be ok or will I have to publish the website again? If there is no need to publish the website, does it work for `css, javascript/jquery` files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only changing visual elements (or in line code that don't rely on a new Project.dll being created) then there is no need to publish the website as long as you are updating the files on the server. If you want VS to send the files to the server for you then you will need to re-publish it.

Publishing is an easy way to build your project, package it and send it to the server so you don't have to mess about with individual files. If you just want to change one file, be it .js , .css or alike then you can just change it.

Comment: I am changing javascript of that is on aspx page. I don't know in which case dll needed to create.

Comment: No it won't. The .dll only needs recreating when you have changes in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're changing...

If you're changing elements that have a direct impact with the codebehind in the aspx.cs, then you'll get a runtime error. For instance, suppose you have an aspx textbox and you change the textbox to a radiobutton, or you change the textbox's id field then you'll have to compile the solution and publish the visual page along with the dll to the server.

If, on the other hand, you're just changing css, javascript, or html, and you're sure that does not have an impact on the codebehind, then you can just publish the visual page.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the code of **views**, then you don't need to publish the site again. If you change **code behind** then you must publish the **dll**. When you change the code the dll of your project changes.